# If $R$ is simple, then $Z(R)$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been stuck on this exercise for three hours, and I think it's time to finally give in. Can anyone help me prove this? I've tried a million ways, from trying to show that $Z(R)$ is simple to trying to use the fact that $Ra=R=aR$ so there exists a $b \in R$ such that $ab=ba=1$ using a hint. But I can't seem to show that $b \in Z(R)$.

Comment: $R$ is simple iff it's simple as a bimodule over itself. Now compute its endomorphism ring as a bimodule, then use Schur's lemma.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I should mention that I'm only starting ring theory and I have no clue what you're talking about

Comment: Ah, I read the last bit of your question. You're actually almost done. Once you know that a nonzero $a \in Z(R)$ has a multiplicative inverse $b \in R$ you only have to show that $b \in Z(R)$. So, you want to show that if $r \in R$ then $rb = br$. Use the fact that $ar = ra$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Got it! Thanks!